# Cannot delete model, if do application return error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have some weird issue. I don't know if I'm doing anything wrong.

### Task

Simple email verification task. As below:

1. User submit request to get new email verification link to his inbox.
2. User click on the link was sent to his inbox which lead to verification page
3. The application verify email and verification token passed in URL
4. If email and token verified. Application will mark user as verified user and delete existing verification code recored/model from email verifications table.

Everything is working fine until deleting the existing record. Each time I try to delete the existing record the application returns 422 Unprocessable entity error.

### Code

Controller

```
public function verifyEmail(EmailVerifications $emailVerificationsRepo,
    Request $request){
    $this->emailVerificationValidator($request);
    $status = $emailVerificationsRepo->verify(
    $request->get('email'),
    $request->get('token')
    );
    if($status){
        return $this->successResponse();
    }
    return $this->errorResponse();
  }
```

Repository

```
/**
   * Verify activation code
   * @param  string $email
   * @param  string $token
   * @return boolean
   */
  public function verify($email, $token){
    $verification = $this->findWhere([
      'email' => $email,
    ])->first();
    if(!$verification){
      return false;
    }
    if(app('hash')->check($token, $verification->verification_code)){
      $user = $verification->user;
      \DB::table('email_verifications')->where('email', $email)->delete();
      $user->verifyEmail();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

/**
* Delete all verification records for giving email
* @param  string $email
* @return boolean
*/
protected function deleteExisting($email){
  return $this->deleteWhere([
    'email' => $email,
  ]);
}
```

Environment:

MacOs, Nginx, Lumen 5.5

Any help? thanks in advance

Comment: where is the code that generate this token and stores it?

Comment: @lagbox i don't think it's relevant. The verification code created with random characters and hashed then saved to database. Everything is working fine. Checking hash are getting passed as expected. The only thing is that I cannot do is deleting the existing record. In other words: If I don't delete the existing verification code from database. The application working fine.

Answer (score -1):

try this:
\DB::table('email_verifications')->where('email', $email)->first()->delete();

Comment: Query Builder is going to return a `stdClass` object or `null` from `first`

Comment: then check if it's null don't delete

Comment: there is no `delete` method on an `stdClass` object